# Webpack, IE8 and ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, webpack

Recent versions of webpack do not support IE8. I have tried with 1.12.12 (which I believed was the last version to support IE8) but still get errors from the un-shimmable `Object.defineProperty`.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2085

What was the last version of webpack to support IE8? Did it ever work with ES6 modules?

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var es3ifyPlugin = require('es3ify-webpack-plugin');
var productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
});
var devPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("dev")
    }
});

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        assessment: "./src/aaa/app.js"
    },
    //devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        path: "../AAA/wwwroot/js",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",
                exclude: "node_modules"
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                // todo: move less compiling to web project 
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader",
                exclude: "node_modules"
            },
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        inline: true,
        proxy: {
            "/api": {
                "target": {
                    host: "localhost",
                    protocol: "http:",
                    port: "58211",
                },
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" }
            }
        },
        publicPath: "/assets/"
    },
    plugins: [
        new es3ifyPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            minChunks: isExternal
        }),
        productionPlugin
        //devPlugin
    ]
}

function isExternal(module) {
    var userRequest = module.userRequest;

    if (typeof userRequest !== "string") {
        return false;
    }

    return userRequest.indexOf("node_modules") >= 0;
}
```

Transpiled code looks like this:

```
exports.test = '123';

webpackJsonp([1, 0], [

  function (module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    'use strict';

    var _imported = __webpack_require__(1);


    alert('test ' + _imported.test);

    function(module, exports) {

        "use strict";

        Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
            value: true
        });
        var test = exports.test = 123;

      }
  ]);
```

Comment: [Webpack 2](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3070) does not support IE8 anymore.

Comment: It's not just webpack 2, webpack 1 is also affected.

Comment: Does 1.13 work for you? From the linked issue it seems that this version might work for IE8.

Comment: I haven't tried 1.13.X but 1.16.X did not work nor did 1.12.12

Comment: Interesting ... from [this blog entry on medium](https://medium.com/react-university/getting-react-to-run-on-ie8-bfc0a3e7543a#.eobjb0f9w) I'd assume that there should be options to get webpack running - except getters/setters are used in the application code. The post was written in April, so I'd think that the current version way back then should work at least.

Comment: [1.13.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commits/v1.13.0) was released on 15th April 2016. So It seems that this should work. Are you sure that you're not using getters/setters within your own application code? Maybe you can create a super simple example with just a hello world sample code and try creating a build using the 1.13 version. The so created code should not use `Object.defineProperty` I guess.

Comment: Webpack 1.14.0 produces what should be IE8 compatible code when tested on a bare-bones module which just calls `console.log`. You must have some other dependency? Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, yes I have removed all my code and installed 1.13.2. The bundles produced work in other browsers but not ie8. code is simply `alert("Hello world");` The error is `SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action sockjs.min.js (3,13318)`. I'm fairly sure this is `Object.defineProperty` failing

Comment: Can you add the module code and webpack code you are using to the question? I'm not seeing anything like that in my testing.

Comment: I have added webpack.config.js, as I said I have reduced the app code to just a single alert.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the minimal example was a great idea and has led me to a working production build of hello world which works in IE8 using webpack 1.13.0. The above mentioned sockjs error was a RED HERRING, only related to webpack-dev-server which obviously I don't need to work with IE8. It may also work with later webpacks (1.X)  as obviously I had a few issues in parallel there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how babel translates ES2015 code by default. In the default (non-loose) mode it [uses `Object.defineProperty`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/), but this can be configured by using loose-mode.

```
// webpack.config.js
module: {
   loaders: [
     {
       test: /\.js$/,
       loader: 'babel-loader',
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       query: {
         presets: [ ['es2015', {"loose": true}] ]
       }
     }
   ]
 }
```

This leads to the following compiled code:

```
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    'use strict';

    var _imported = __webpack_require__(1);

    var _imported2 = _interopRequireDefault(_imported);

    function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

    console.log('test ' + _imported2.default);

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";

    exports.__esModule = true;
    var test = 123;

    exports.default = test;

/***/ }
/******/ ])
```

#### Old answer

From the discussion as this has solved your issue:

[1.13.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commits/v1.13.0) was released on 15th April 2016. So It seems that this should work. Are you sure that you're not using getters/setters within your own application code? Maybe you can create a super simple example with just a hello world sample code and try creating a build using the 1.13 version. The so created code should not use `Object.defineProperty` I guess.

Comment: While the config above works ok for hello world with no modules, as soon as I bring modules in I get the error from this line `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
     value: true
 });` in the webpack generated code. If you have a working set up for IE8 can you share it?

Comment: In an absolute minimal setup using webpack 1.13 `Object.defineProperty` is not introduced. Please see [code](https://github.com/dotcs/webpack-ie8-example) and compiled [bundle.js](https://github.com/dotcs/webpack-ie8-example/blob/master/bundle.js).

Comment: Thankyou. This shows that it works with `require()` but not `import` (es6 modules).

Comment: I have added the compiled code to the question, as you can see, using import results in `defineProperty` calls

Comment: You're right, when using [ES2015 modules](https://github.com/dotcs/webpack-ie8-example/tree/es2015-modules) the problem occurs. See [bundle.js](https://github.com/dotcs/webpack-ie8-example/blob/es2015-modules/bundle.js).

Comment: But this comes from babel, not from webpack: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/

Comment: Okay got it, you have to use loose mode of Babel's ES2015 plugin. See [demo code](https://github.com/dotcs/webpack-ie8-example/blob/es2015-modules/bundle.js) and configuration within this project. It was [mentioned here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/). `query: { presets: [ ['es2015', {"loose": true}] ]  }` for the babel plugin does the job. I'll adjust the answer above.

Comment: Thankyou, this is the answer that I was looking for. I am very grateful to you for tracking this one down.

Comment: I should add that the construct `export * from` will still produce code using `Object.defineProperty` but this can be avoided.