# Typescript + Webpack + IE11:

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, webpack

I am seeing the error below when running my application in IE11. I tried the [solution suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41250237/1419386) using Babel but it does not work. Is Babel only for JavaScript files?

How can I configure webpack to transpile this into something IE11 understands?

> Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty'

This is the corresponding line in the transpiled JavaScript.

index.bundle.js

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

webpack.config.js

```
   module.exports = {  
      entry: './src/entry/index.ts',
      output: {
        filename: 'index.bundle.js'
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
      }
    }
```